# How to improve the aspect of ggplot histograms with log scales and discrete values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to improve the clarity and aspect of a histogram of discrete values which I need to represent with a log scale.

Please consider the following MWE

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(dist = as.integer(rlnorm(1000, sdlog = 2)))
class(data$dist)
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) + geom_histogram()
```

which produces

[image]

and then

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) + geom_line() + scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,2,3,4,5,10,100))
```

which probably is even worse

[image]

since now it gives the impression that the something is missing between "1" and "2", and also is not totally clear which bar has value "1" (bar is on the *right* of the tick) and which bar has value "2" (bar is on the *left* of the tick).

I understand that technically ggplot provides the "right" visual answer for a log scale. Yet as observer I have some problem in understanding it.

Is it possible to improve something?

EDIT:

This what happen when I applied Jaap solution to my real data

[image]

Where do the dips between x=0 and x=1 and between x=1 and x=2 come from? My value are discrete, but then why the plot is also mapping x=1.5 and x=2.5?

Comment: This might be trivial but, try decreasing number of bins ??

Comment: @koundy That doesn't really help in my opinion. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 14):

The first thing that comes to mind, is playing with the `binwidth`. But that doesn't give a great solution either:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=10) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.015,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

gives:
[image]

---

In this case it is probably better to use a density plot. However, when you use `scale_x_log10` you will get a warning message (`Removed 524 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density)`). This can be resolved by using a ***log plus one*** transformation.

The following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) +
  stat_density(aes(y=..count..), color="black", fill="blue", alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,10,30,100,300,1000), trans="log1p", expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,125,250,375,500,625,750), expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

will give this result:
[image]

Comment: For some strange reason, using your solution on my real data I have a dip between x=0 and x=1 and between x=1 and x=2 Why? There's no value to map between 0 and 1 since as in the MWE my values are discrete. (Picture added)

Comment: As the sample data you provided are discrete as well, that's probably not the problem. Looking at your plot, it might have something to do with the definition of your y-axis. The ticks are really cluttered together at the bottom of the y-axis, which is strange. Could you share the exact code and a `dput` of the data (or a large enough sample of your data) you used? Without that it's quite hard to tell what the exact cause of this behavior is.

Comment: log1p, nice, did not know about that!

Answer (score 5):

I am wondering, what if, y-axis is scaled instead of x-axis. It will results into few warnings wherever values are 0, but may serve your purpose.

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(dist = as.integer(rlnorm(1000, sdlog = 2)))
class(data$dist)
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) + geom_histogram() + scale_y_log10()
```

[image: Basic Graph]

Also you may want to display frequencies as data labels, since people might ignore the y-scale and it takes some time to realize that y scale is logarithmic.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) + geom_histogram(fill = 'skyblue', color = 'grey30') + scale_y_log10() +
  stat_bin(geom="text", size=3.5, aes(label=..count.., y=0.8*(..count..)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A solution could be to convert your data to a factor:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(dist = as.integer(rlnorm(1000, sdlog = 2)))
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(dist))) + 
    geom_histogram(stat = "count") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Comment: You don't need to do that upfront, you can also convert it to a factor variable inside the `ggplot` function: `ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(dist))) + geom_histogram()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and, inspired by @Jaap's answer, I fiddled with the histogram binwidth using the x-axis in log scale.

If you use binwidth = 0.201, the bars will be juxtaposed as expected. However, this means you can only have up to five bars between two x coordinates.

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(dist = as.integer(rlnorm(1000, sdlog = 2)))
class(data$dist)
ggplot(data, aes(x=dist)) + 
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.201, color = 'red') + 
   scale_x_log10()
```

Result:

[image]