# Minor ticks on log10 scale using ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a dataframe of ~108m rows of data, in 7 columns. I use this R script to make a boxplot of it:

```
ggplot(expanded_results, aes(factor(hour), dynamic_nox)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#6699FF", outlier.size = 0.5, lwd=.1) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1, colour="red")) +
  ylab(expression(Exposure~to~NO[x])) + 
  xlab(expression(Hour~of~the~day)) +
  ggtitle("Hourly exposure to NOx") +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        legend.position="none")
```

The graph looks like this. It's pretty much fine, however it would be better to have a value towards the top of the Y axis. I guess it should be something like 1000 given the Y axis is a log10 scale. I'm not sure how to do this though?

[image]

Any ideas please?

EDIT: In response to DrDom:
Try to add `scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,100,1000))`. The output of doing that, is this:

[image]

The output of doing the following:
`scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,100,1000), limits=c(0,1000))`

Is an error of:

```
Error in seq.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], length = dots[[3L]][[1L]]:
'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

In respnonse to Jaap who suggested the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(expanded_results, aes(factor(hour), dynamic_nox)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#6699FF", outlier.size = 0.5, lwd=.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1, colour="red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,100,1000,3000), trans="log1p") +
  labs(title="Hourly exposure to NOx", x=expression(Hour~of~the~day), y=expression(Exposure~to~NO[x])) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"), axis.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"), legend.position="none")
```

It produces this graph. Have I done something wrong? I'm still missing a '1000' tick label? A tick inbetween the 10 and the 100 would also be good given that is where most of the data is?

[image]

Comment: Try to add `scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,100,1000))` or `scale_y_log10(breaks=c(0,10,100,1000), limits=c(0,1000))`

Comment: Hi DrDom. Thanks for your suggestions. The results are added to my post above. Note that the data looks a bit different as running the graph creation again takes about 20 minutes, so I just used a subset of the data for demonstration purpose. Not quite there yet. :-(

Comment: I have written a function which does that automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325289/3082472

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `scale_y_log10` you can also use `scale_y_continuous` together with a log transformation from the `scales` package. When you use the `log1p` transformation, you are also able to include a `0` in your breaks: `scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000), trans="log1p")`

Your complete code will then look like this (notice that I also combined the title arguments in `labs`):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(expanded_results, aes(factor(hour), dynamic_nox)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="#6699FF", outlier.size = 0.5, lwd=.1) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=1, colour="red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,3,10,30,100,300,1000,3000), trans="log1p") +
  labs(title="Hourly exposure to NOx", x=expression(Hour~of~the~day), y=expression(Exposure~to~NO[x])) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12, colour="black"), axis.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=12, colour="black"), legend.position="none")
```

Comment: I thought that it should read 

trans="log10"

instead of

trans="log1p"

Can you clarify?

Comment: @TheRealJimShady You can use both. However when your `dynamic_nox` has values of `0`, these observations will be excluded. `log1p` will add `1` to the value and then calculate the log-value. In this way also values of `0` will be included. See [this answer for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646594/how-to-improve-the-aspect-of-ggplot-histograms-with-log-scales-and-discrete-valu/24649522#246495220)

Comment: Hi Jaap. Thanks again for your guidance. I've put the output of your suggestions in my question above. Would you take a glance please? I'm missing some tick marks still. Not sure what to do about that? Thank you.

Comment: @TheRealJimShady Can you include a `dput` of (part of) your data in your question ([see here for an explanation how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2204410))? That would make it much easier for me to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think I've figured it out now actually. I've done this and it seems to work well:

scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,10,100,300,1000,3000), trans="log1p", labels=c(0,10,100,300,1000,3000))

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your log scale by adding arguments `breaks=` to `scale_y_log10()`, only there shouldn't be a 0 value because from those values also log is calculated.

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:10000,y=1:10000)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+
      scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,5,10,85,300,5000))
```